# Reading and Outputting the Group and Username Permissions on Folders

Tags: powershell

I was wondering on how to get started on writing a powershell script that will allow me to grab the the Groups and Usernames who are granted permission to a folder as well as the current permissions that they have for that folder and then output that information into some text format.

It would also be convenient if it could scan all the folders and sub-folders in a directory. Again all I need is to be pointed to the right resources and I;ll pick it up from there, I'm just not at all familiar when it comes to coding in powershell. Thank you for reading.

Comment: `get-childitem -recurse` `get-acl` `get-adgroupmember` `get-aduser` should be some commandlets to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `Get-Acl` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/Get-Acl) to retrieve the Access Control List(s) for a specific item. The `Access` property will contain the access control entries you're looking for:

```
Get-Acl C:\path\to\folder\or\file |Select -Expand Access |Export-Csv C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I've already figured out how to go through the directory and out it the why I need it. Thanks again!